# Not able to install feature pack for web services WAS 6.1

Tags: web-services, websphere, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad-7.5

I tried creating the `Webservices` on my `RAD 7.5 with WAS 6.1` but it says that the feature pack for `Webservices JAX-WS` is not available.

When i tried installing the feature pack by using the Modify option from `IBM Installation manager` it's asking me some type of repository.

`""A repository used for installation is unavailable. To continue, make the repository available"`

`Specify the repository for package for IBM Websphere Application Server 6.1 (32 bit) Test environment 6.1.0.47. Alternatively you can specify a repository location and browse for a repository location`

I am not sure what repository location needs to be provided here.

Comment: I suppose you need download proper feature pack dist and add it like new repository in IBM Installation Manager. What dist you trying to use now?

Comment: When I am trying to modify the packages from IBM installation manager its already giving me option to add feature pack for Web services but later on its asking for some repository path. I downloaded some pack from ibm named "6.1.0-WS-WAS-WSFEP-WinX32" but IBM installation manager is not taking this as a valid repository.

Comment: Instead in RAD 7.0 with WAS 6.1, i dont have to add any feature pack additionally and its working fine. I dont know why IBM removed that feature pack from rad 7.5 that we have to install it separatly.

Comment: I also tried installing fix pack "6.1.0-WS-WASWebSvc-WinX32-FP0000047" using Websphere Update installer 7.0.1. But its giving me a message "This is not applicable".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install it manually as listed in link below :
http://docs.myeclipseide.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.genuitec.eclipse.blue.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftutorials%2Fblue_install_websphere6.1%2Findex.html

The profiles have to be recreated based on WebServices Templates as existing profiles cannot use the Feature pack. Also WAS v7.x has this feature specs post GA.

NOTE : You will have to install WebServices Base code on WAS first, then PK53084 (using Update Installer)  and then fixpack for WebServices matching WAS fixpack ( using Update installer). 
The only down side is that you would have to use Update installer to apply updates to WAS and WebServices code. IM cannot be used to apply updates to test environment.